# What happens to auc when true positive rate grows

Tags: metric, confusion-matrix, auc, roc

How does change in true positive rate affects AUC? Does increase of TPR lead to increase of AUC as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theoretically** if you are able increase TPR keeping the FPR constant your AUC will increase.
Lets understand the ROC curve first to understand why it happens :

AUC is calculated from ROC curve. ROC curve shows the performance of model (classification) at all the thresholds. The two parameters are as follows

```
  True Positive Rate : TP / (TP + FN) (TP : True Positive , FN : False Negative)

  False Positive Rate : FP / (FP + TN) (FP : False Positive, TB : True Negative)
```

Ideally for different thresholds, you plot values of TPR and FPR.

The image below represent a ROC curve, with TPR on Y axis and FPR on X axis ([Image Sorce](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5)):

[image]

Ideally, Both FPR and TPR are interrelated. If you lower the threshold both FPR and TPR will increase.